# Get Instagram photo links of a hashtag using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, instagram

I wrote this methods that store instagram links in an ArrayList based on a hashtag or list of hashtags and the number of desired links.
Something to notice is that if I tell the program to get 10 links it will get 12 links instead because of how Instagram places the photos in a grid style but after 10 iterations it stops and the ArrayList is cleared, is this considered bad or it doesnt matter?

```
private void getLinks(TextArea logbox) throws InterruptedException {
        utils.addLogLine(logbox, "[+] Obteniendo links con los tags especificados...");

        int numberOfRows = (int) Math.ceil(((float) numberOfLikes / 3));
        int numberOfRowsPerTag = (int) Math.ceil(((float) numberOfRows / tags.size()));

        //Page needs to load more images after first load
        if (numberOfRowsPerTag > 4) {
            for (int x = 0; x < tags.size(); x++) {
                searchTag(tags.get(x));
                int numberOfPageDowns = (int) Math.ceil(((float) numberOfRowsPerTag / 4));

                WebElement loadMoreBtn = utils.fluentWait(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/article/div[2]/a"), driver);
                loadMoreBtn.click();
                WebElement pageBody = utils.fluentWait(By.tagName("body"), driver);

                for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPageDowns; y++) {
                    pageBody.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
                    pageBody.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
                    utils.waitGivenSeconds(2);
                }

                for (int z = 0; z < numberOfRowsPerTag; z++) {
                    int row = z + 1;
                    getPhotolinksFromRow(row);
                }
                utils.addLogLine(logbox, "[+] Links para #" + tags.get(x) + " añadidos!");
            }
        } else {
            for (int x = 0; x < tags.size(); x++) {
                searchTag(tags.get(x));
                for (int z = 0; z < numberOfRowsPerTag; z++) {
                    int row = z + 1;
                    getPhotolinksFromRow(row);
                }
                utils.addLogLine(logbox, "[+] Links para #" + tags.get(x) + " añadidos!");
            }
        }
    }

private void getPhotolinksFromRow(int row) {
        WebElement firstPhoto = utils.fluentWait(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + row + "]/div[1]/a"), driver);
        WebElement secondPhoto = utils.fluentWait(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + row + "]/div[2]/a"), driver);
        WebElement thirdPhoto = utils.fluentWait(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + row + "]/div[3]/a"), driver);

        String firstLink = firstPhoto.getAttribute("href");
        String secondLink = secondPhoto.getAttribute("href");
        String thirdLink = thirdPhoto.getAttribute("href");


        String[] firstLinkStripped = firstLink.split("\\?");
        String[] secondLinkStripped = secondLink.split("\\?");
        String[] thirdLinkStripped = thirdLink.split("\\?");

        List<String> tempLinks = Arrays.asList(firstLinkStripped[0], secondLinkStripped[0], thirdLinkStripped[0]);
        links.addAll(tempLinks);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit:  what is the desired output and what is the current output? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Desired output and current output is the same, the program is working fine, I'm just wondering if maybe I can refactor something and if the style of code is alright since I have never work in a team and in my opinion my code tends to be a little messy

Comment: And to explain a little bit: Instagram shows photos in a grid of 4 rows and 3 columns, this algorithm checks if the first grid is enough or it has to load more grids and then iterates over the grids and gets the link of every photo